# How to convert one country time stamp into another country timestamp without using tzset() and handle DST properly in C?

Tags: c, linux, dst, mktime

Lets assume my application is running in one country(src : India), My friends who live in European country wants to read some specific data from my application in his country time stamp i.e german timestamp. If my friend's country lends in DST(Day light saving), my application shall handle that as well.

Below are steps I've followed.

- Step-1 : converted system time(**IST**) to **UTC** time, sine application is running in India.
- Step-2 : Added **UTC+01:00** offset to UTC time derived in step-1 to get the German local time.
- Step-3 : Here I've got the German local time, but my application timezone is still **IST** not **CET**. How to change it to **CET** so that I can check `tm_isdst` flag whether **DST** is in place or not and adjust the time back or forth by 1 hour. Note that *I'm not allowed to use tzset() or any timezone environment variable*.

Sample code :

```
/* step-1 : get the system time */
time_t now = time(NULL);
struct tm *systemTime = localtime(&now);
printf("step-1 system time [%s] timezone[%s]\n", asctime(systemTime), (char*)systemTime->tm_zone);

/* step-2 : get the UTC time */
struct tm *utcTime = gmtime(&now);//return utc
printf("step-2 UTC time [%s] timezone[%s]\n", asctime(utcTime), (char*)utcTime->tm_zone);

/*  step-3 : get the local Berlin/German time from UTC time */
time_t localGermanTime = mktime(utcTime);
struct tm *localGermanTimeTm = localtime(&localGermanTime);
localGermanTimeTm->tm_zone = "CEST"; //Failed : Tried forcefully setting but next mktime() call reset it
localGermanTimeTm->tm_hour += 1; //+01:00 (lets assume german time is UTC+01:00)
localGermanTimeTm->tm_min += 0;
//added mktime to normalize above manipulation 
time_t normalizeTimeRet = mktime(localGermanTimeTm);
struct tm* localGermanTimeTmAdjusted = localtime(&normalizeTimeRet);
if(normalizeTimeRet == -1)
{
    printf("mktime() normalize went in-correct");
}

/*  step-4 : Adjust the DST */
if(localGermanTimeTmAdjusted->tm_isdst) //problem is this localGermanTimeTmAdjusted is having the germany current time but time zone is still IST so this didn't hit
{
    /*  adjust the hours by +1 */
    localGermanTimeTmAdjusted->tm_hour += 1;
    printf("step-4 local german/other time is in DST timezone[%s]\n", (char*)localGermanTimeTmAdjusted->tm_zone);
}
else
{
    printf("local german/other time is not in DST\n");
}
/* step-5 : Normalize above result by calling mktime() */
time_t normalizeTimeDstRet = mktime(localGermanTimeTmAdjusted);
struct tm* localGermanTimeTmDstAdjusted = localtime(&normalizeTimeDstRet);

printf("step-5 german/other time after normalizing DST [%s] timezone [%s]\n", asctime(localGermanTimeTmDstAdjusted), (char*)localGermanTimeTmDstAdjusted->tm_zone);
```

Above is achievable with `tzset()` but since one part of application where user tried to read some data, that is happening very frequently hence I can't use the `tzset()` as this will impact the performance.

Sample code o/p:

```
[root@achal appAchal]# date && ./a.out
Tue Oct 19 16:25:23 IST 2021
step-1 system time [Tue Oct 19 16:25:23 2021] timezone[IST]
step-2 UTC time [Tue Oct 19 10:55:23 2021] timezone[GMT]
local german/other time is not in DST
step-5 german/other time after normalizing DST [Tue Oct 19 11:55:23 2021] timezone [IST]
```

Comment: Do you have access to the `tzalloc` and `localtime_rz` functions?

Comment: @SteveSummit yes its accessible.

Comment: You want to convert your localtime → UTC → some other time zone.  You can do localtime → UTC using `mktime`.  Then use `tzalloc` to get a "timezone" pointer for your other (German) timezone.  Then use `localtime_rz` to convert your UTC timestamp to that other zone.

Comment: Actually, you may not even need the `mktime` step.  The `time` function is already giving you a UTC timestamp.

Comment: My bad, I don't see `localtime_rz`  in `time.h` or in other headers.

Comment: That's why I asked.  `localtime_tz` is, unfortunately, not standard.

Comment: The "official" solution, using only standard functions, is to reset the `TZ` environment variable, ghastly and nonreentrant and inefficient-seeming as it is.

Comment: How are your colleagues in Germany accessing your database?  If there's a process involved (a Unix/Linux process, that is), you should be able to set TZ in just that process to their timezone.

Comment: I'm not sure which Linux distros include the new TZ functions such as `tzalloc`. Debian and Ubuntu don't. Arch Linux looks like it might (needs `-ltz` link option for them). No idea about Red Hat, SuSE, Manjaro, etc.

Comment: @IanAbbott I'm not aware of any systems that include them, either.  (And they're not really "new" any more, either.)  They claim to be BSD-inspired, but my BSD-inspired Mac doesn't seem to have them, either.

Comment: I recommend reading http://www.catb.org/esr/time-programming/ for a thorough treatment of how time handling in C/Unix actually work.  The functions I've been mentioning are covered in the section on the "Berkeley multiple-timezone API".

Comment: One option may be to add localtime.c and various header files from tzcode to the project.

Comment: You can download the "tzcode" package from https://www.iana.org/time-zones and build it yourself.  That will give you `localtime_tz`.  (I can't say how much tinkering you might have to do to get that package's functions to cleanly override your local libc's.  For me it hasn't been difficult, but YMMV.)

Comment: Thanks @SteveSummit for the input. I'll give a try to tzcode.

Comment: Some more background: A `time_t` value is always in UTC.  You convert a `time_t` value into human-readable form, using your system's time zone (or, equivalently, your environment's `TZ` setting) using `localtime`.  But if you're lucky, you may also be able to convert a `time_t` into a human-readable time in *any* timezone, using `localtime_rz`.  (But if you don't have `localtime_rz`, and if you can't or won't fiddle with `TZ` and call `tzset`, you may be out of luck, because I don't know of another way.)

Comment: One tip: if you build tzcode for yourself, you will probably have to find and adjust the setting in the Makefile that tells it where to find the zoneinfo files on your system.

Comment: Another way to get the code is to import the "time_rz" module from [GNU Gnulib](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/).