# Poor query performance when setting timeZone

Tags: mysql, performance, timezone

I'm using a query to sum data over one day using simple query:
to clarify the syntax, it is inside a stored procedure

```
SET TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Dubai'; 
SELECT 
r.id, 
r.name, 
SUM(dd.activeEnergy) as activeEnergy, 
FROM rooms r
LEFT JOIN devicesData dd  ON dd.roomId = r.id 
WHERE dd.createdAt >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND dd.createdAt < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())
GROUP BY r.id
```

Interestingly for larger query (90 000 rows), the query hangs and loop forever.
If I remove the

```
SET TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Dubai';
```

The query will work ok with short response time (2s)

As a resolution, I've set instead variables:

```
DECLARE start INT UNSIGNED; 
DECLARE end INT unsigned ; 
SET start   =   unix_timestamp(CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 DAY ,'Asia/Dubai','GMT'));  
SET end     =   unix_timestamp(CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE() ,'Asia/Dubai','GMT'));  
..

WHERE dd.createdAt >= start
AND dd.createdAt < end
```

now the query works ok even on larger volume.

There is a hint on tzset() creating a bottleneck on queries on this question:
[How to convert one country time stamp into another country timestamp without using tzset() and handle DST properly in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69629736/how-to-convert-one-country-time-stamp-into-another-country-timestamp-without-usi)
and on this article:
https://alibaba-cloud.medium.com/mysql-practices-how-to-handle-slow-sql-execution-due-to-time-zone-setting-8c11ad29356a

This seems to indicate setting timezone will have a performance impact. It seems to fit to description above.

is it really so strange that timezone should not be set before making a query?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE devicesData`

Answer (score 0):

Change `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN`.  With LEFT, it is gathering all the 'missing' rows and unnecessarily SUMming up the NULLs it gets.

Even better:

```
SET TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Dubai';
SELECT  r.id, r.name, 
        ( SELECT SUM(dd.activeEnergy)
            FROM devicesData dd
            WHERE  dd.roomId = r.id
              AND  dd.createdAt >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
              AND  dd.createdAt  < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())
        ) as activeEnergy,
    FROM  rooms r
```

This should avoid the `GROUP BY` also.

If that is not good enough, I may have another trick.